# can we have 2 Database server for the single sharepoint Farm?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

We are having huge data around 4tb in our sharepoint site and we want to get new set of database server and point our application to new database server but we have other web applications also which needs to be on old Database server. so we want just one web application to point to new database server for better performance so can we have 2 database server for single farm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Please take the below steps:

Go to SharePoint CA-> Application Management-> Manange Database, choose your web application and add new conetent dabase. You could choose a new DB server for your web application.

[image]

[image]